# How to use multiple checkbox and FILTER to filter data from another tab?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to use multiple checkbox to select which values should be filtered from another tab's column, in order to create a Dashboard.

Dashboard:
[Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJySx.png)

Work days:
[Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uj9J8.png)

copyable sample sheet:
https://cryptpad.fr/sheet/#/2/sheet/edit/cygmkx-J45fsZarVMRowgkn6/

So I'm trying to create a formula that says: For each value in the present tab's column A, if the adjacent cell from column B is equal TRUE, use the value as a keyword to filter a column data from another tab. If 'Clark' and 'Monica' correspondent checkbox are marked, the results must include both.

This is the closest I got:

`=IF(AND(B2=TRUE);filter('Work days'!A2:A1000;'Work days'!C2:C1000=A2);IF(AND(B3=TRUE);filter('Work days'!A2:A1000;'Work days'!C2:C1000=A3);IF(AND(B4=TRUE);filter('Work days'!A2:A1000;'Work days'!C2:C1000=A4);IF(AND(B5=TRUE);filter('Work days'!A2:A1000;'Work days'!C2:C1000=A5)))))`

But it will only filter the first checkbox that are TRUE. If it filters all that are TRUE, I can accept the fact that it will require some typing to be updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following formula-

```
=REDUCE(Sheet1!A1:C1,FILTER(Sheet1!G2:G5,Sheet1!H2:H5=TRUE),LAMBDA(a,x,{a;FILTER(A:C,C:C=x)}))
```

To include `All` try-

```
=IF(H6=TRUE,FILTER(A:C,A:A<>""),REDUCE(Sheet1!A1:C1,FILTER(Sheet1!G2:G5,Sheet1!H2:H5=TRUE),LAMBDA(a,x,{a;FILTER(A:C,C:C=x)})))
```

[image]

Comment: What if the columns A:C are from sheet1, and columns G:H plus the formula are in the sheet2? 

I tried updating your formula like this:

=REDUCE('Work days'!A1:C1;FILTER('Dashboard'!G2:G5;'Dashboard'!H2:H5=TRUE);LAMBDA(a,x,{a;FILTER('Work days'!A:C;'Work days'!C:C=x)}))  . Where Work days = sheet1 and Dashboard = sheet2. But it didn't worked. Thanks, by the way

Comment: @Vic7152 You formula in comments seems okay. What error are you getting? Can you share a google-sheet so that I can direct check that?

Comment: ERROR: In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows.

Sure, here it is: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BzWnKwM-BGpJ4BmsU2X0uvtazU4pJX9_/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=111162399302969153509&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: Sorry, the error is Formula parse error